2D Canvas text has fragmentation issues in 3D
I'm using a 2D canvas to generate 3D text labels and running into an issue where the text on the labels has missing 'chunks' in square shapes. It seems to only occur if the label is deeply nested in a group of a group. If the label is higher up in the child chain it's fine. The fragmentation changes every refresh of the page so it's happening on the initial render. I've tried increase the resolution which seems to help but never fully removes the issue. Anyone know how to resolve?




Could you provide your code?

@ŁukaszD.Mastalerz Here's the label class https://pastebin.com/yVvCyhLG
